# Access 2 VM's with one IPv4

Tags: linux, nat

I have two Virtual Machines.
The 1st VM is running Debian 8.2 and the 2nd one is running Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS
Also I have one Public IPv4

The IPv4 assigns in only one server at a time.
I assume that I need to create a NAT for access both servers from the same IP.

At the dashboard I can create a private network.
So, my question is, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This mostly depends on what kind of services you want to reach from the one IPv4 address.

let's say that :

- 90.90.90.90 is your Public IPv4 (app.domain.org / app2.domain.org)
- 192.168.1.1 is your Debian Server
- 192.168.1.2 is your Ubuntu Server

The first thing that comes in mind would be to use a `port forwarding` mechanism : you will redirect packets to the right server/port regarding the requested target port :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wan0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wan0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:80
```

The advantage is that you can serve anything (from SSH to RDP, and of course HTTP).
But you will have to get rid of some standard server/protocol ports.

Another option could be the use of a Reverse Proxy based on Server Name (e.g mod_proxy from Apache):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName app.domain.org
   ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.1:80/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.1:80/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName app2.domain.org
   ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.2:80/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.2:80/
</VirtualHost>
```

This one is mostly suitable for HTTP protocol.

There are options.
For a more accurate answer you would need to provide more details about services you intend to publish.
BTW, i strongly suggest some readings below :
http://www.systutorials.com/816/port-forwarding-using-iptables/
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Ubuntu is used for various things such as VNC, SSH, P2P etc.
Debian is used only for Web Hosting and File Transfers with (SFTP).

I created a private network. Ubuntu is on 192.168.0.2 and Debian is on 192.168.0.3

So, I should enter some commands on iptables to allow access to specific ports on Debian such as apache and MySQL ports?